# Indicate target directory of stack build executable

Tags: haskell, build, haskell-stack

I used to build a project with the following command:

```sh
stack ghc -- src/Main.hs -o build/myexecutablefile -odir build -hidir build -isrc
```

Now I've installed the project as a proper Stack package with `stack.yaml` and `project.cabal` files, I'm able to build it using the simpler `stack build` command.

However, I can't figure out how to specify, as I used to, that the executable file should go to the `project/build` directory. Currently, the executable file goes into the `/Users/myself/project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/993e24b...1126d52/8.8.4/bin` folder and I haven't succeeded in changing it so far.

I've tried setting `local-bin-path: ./build/` in `stack.yaml`, to no effect. `stack path` shows the correct value, but when running `stack build`, the executable still goes to the same destination folder as mentioned just above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put the binaries in their place:

```
stack install
```

which is a shortcut for

```
stack build --copy-bins
```